# Delay in creating selenium chrome node pod by keda operator kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium chrome node to scaling up and down pods with the help of keda operator.Based on the selenium hub queue size scaledobject will create pod

if queue size is 20 it suppose to create 20 pods first pod creating quickly but after 30 sec the second set of pods are getting created later again after 30 sec other set of pods are creating

scaled object deployment file

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  labels:
    deploymentName: selenium-chrome-node
    scaledobject.keda.sh/name: selenium-grid-chrome-scaledobject
  name: selenium-grid-chrome-scaledobject
  namespace: selenium
spec:
  maxReplicaCount: 100
  minReplicaCount: 0
  pollingInterval: 2
  scaleTargetRef:
    name: selenium-chrome-node
  triggers:
  - metadata:
      browserName: chrome
      unsafeSsl: "true"
      url: http://selenium-hub.selenium.svc:4444/graphql
    type: selenium-grid
```

chrome node deployment file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: selenium-chrome-node
  namespace: selenium
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 0
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: selenium-chrome-node
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS
          value: "1"
        - name: SE_NODE_OVERRIDE_MAX_SESSIONS
          value: "false"
        - name: SE_NODE_SESSION_TIMEOUT
          value: "300"
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: selenium-event-bus-config
        image: selenium/node-chrome:116.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: selenium-chrome-node
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5553
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1500m
            memory: 3Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 900m
            memory: 1Gi
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /dev/shm
          name: dshm
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - emptyDir:
          medium: Memory
        name: dshm
```

How can I ignore those 30 seconds deploy in pod creation by scaled object. It should create pod one after other immediately